# Swift 3.0 json frameworks compile errors

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ios10

I am making a project in swift 3.0.

I have installed pods for SwiftHTTP and JSONJoy-Swift. Yesterday it was giving me errors to convert it to latest swift3.0 code even though it already was. I did pod deginerate and few other things and it started working(not sure of the steps or which step made it work)

```
pod 'SwiftHTTP', '~> 2.0.0'
pod 'JSONJoy-Swift', '~> 2.0.1'
```

Now today I included SwiftyJSON and the problem is occuring again with the SwiftHTTP and JSONJoy-Swift even when i removed it. I have both versions of XCode(7.3 and 8) since i have some old projects which havent been migrated yet.
What is the cause of this and how to solve it?

[image: convert to swift 3.0 error]

Comment: Ok i did pod denigrate and removed the pod cache and installed it again. Restarted Computer/XCode added SWIFT_VERSION  (3.0) in pod files and it is working now.

Comment: Than answer your own question.